# Why does this ajax call only run once

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

In my Html I have this ajax function that is meant o be called every 5 seconds to check if task is completed, and continue untilk it has and then redirect.

But it only seems to be called once, what is wrong with it

```
      <script>
      /**
        Check Progress
        */
        function checkprogress(routepath)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                {
                    var response = xhr.responseText;
                    if(response.endsWith('.html')||response.startsWith('/'))
                    {
                        window.location.href=response;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById('progressbars').innerHTML = response;
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET',routepath + '.update_progress', true);
            xhr.send();
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        setInterval(checkprogress('/editsongs'), 5000);
    </script>
```

Comment: you cannot pass an argument into a function if the function is an argument itself. wrap your function inside setInterval in an anonymous function instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function is evaluating to undefined.
use an anonymous function instead:

```
setInterval(function(){checkprogress('/editsongs')}, 5000);
```

setInterval(checkprogress('./editsongs'), 5000) will not call checkProgress with that argument, instead it will execute checkProgress as soon as you call the setInterval, returning the result which will be undefined. So basically your code currently is:

```
checkprogress('/editsongs');
setInterval(undefined, 5000);
```

Take this as an example:

```js
function add(a, b){
  console.log("adding "+a+" and "+b);
  return a+b;
}
console.log("result:", add(1,2));


//setInterval(add(1,2), 5000);
//is basically
//setInterval(3, 5000);

//therefore use an anonymous function:
setInterval(function(){
  console.log("result:", add(4,5));
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Im not getting it, is this to do with it being an asynchrous ajax call rather than a synchronous one, the parameter is just to allow the same same javascript functin to be used in different pages, and I just want it to check progress every 5 seconds until it gets a url to redirect to.

Comment: You are not passing a function to setInterval which is what it expects, instead you are passing `undefined` because you are calling the function (which returns undefiend) instead of just passing a function to it, and so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm, I did as you say and now its not calling it at all !

Comment: I had the ending curly bracket in wrong place, ok thanks works

Answer (score 0):

Because you dont pass function you run function you cann look like this

```
  setInterval(checkprogress, 5000, '/editsongs');
```